# Html - display text for the link inside whatsapp share button

Tags: html, whatsapp

I have the following code:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https//google.com" class="whatsapp-link" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"
   target="_blank">Share link</a>
```

I want the text that is sent in the message in whatsapp to appear like this:

"[Click Here](https://google.com)"

Instead of apearing like this:

"https://google.com"

How do I do this?

This is unrelated to the html, I want the link that is in the whatsapp message to have a display text, the html display text for the link works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Does the above not appear as "Share link"?

Comment: Yes, I want the whatsapp message to appear as click here, unrelated to the display text of the a element